# Xtext conditional formatting

Tags: java, xtext

My grammar look something like this

```
NAME value
```

I use the genereated xtend file to do some formatting

```
    /*
    * generated by Xtext
     */
    class MyFormatter extends AbstractDeclarativeFormatter {

    @Inject extension MyGrammarAccess g
    override protected void configureFormatting(FormattingConfig c) {

        c.setAutoLinewrap(700)

        c.setLinewrap().around(g.getSpecificRule)

        c.setSpace("  ").between(n.getNamerule, n.getValueRule)
    }
}
```

I'd like to do some formatting depending on the length of my Name Rule,
so I can put the value on a specific column, so instead of two spaces I'd like to put a variable number of spaces depending on the length of the name.

can someone guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a new formatting API, that allows you to format based on the actual semantic and node models: https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#formatting. The old formatting API is based only on the grammar structure.